# Xlookup with Multiple Criteria using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, xlookup

In Excel, you can have multiple criteria when using the `Xlookup` feature.

A "normal" `Xlookup` looks something like this:

```
=xlookup("ThingToLookFor", "Search Range", "Return Range")
```

A multiple criteria `Xlookup` looks something like this:

```
=xlookup("ThingToLookFor" & "OtherThingToLookFor", "Search Range 1" & "Search Range 2", "Return Range")
```

I'm trying to do a multiple criteria Xlookup in VBA. Using `&` combines the two strings together, so that's no good.

What is the correct version of this in VBA?

```
WorksheetFunction.Xlookup("ThingToLookFor" & OtherThingToLookFor", "Search Range 1" & "Search Range 2", "Return Range")?
```

*Note: I did discover "Evaluate". I can make it work, but I'm not sure I like it.*

---

A more specific example:

```vb
Sub xlookup_test()

    Dim Lookup_Value_1 As String
    Lookup_Value_1 = "My Document"
    
    Dim Lookup_Value_2 As String
    Lookup_Value_2 = "Sales"
    
    Dim Search_List_1 As Range
    Set Search_List_1 = Document_Control.Range("DC_Document_Type")
    
    Dim Search_List_2 As Range
    Set Search_List_2 = Document_Control.Range("DC_Document_Name")
    
    Dim Return_List As Range
    Set Return_List = Document_Control.Range("DC_Document_ID")
    
    Dim Return_Value As String

    ' this is the problem line    
    Return_Value = WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Lookup_Value_1 & Lookup_Value_2, Search_List_1 & Search_List_2, Return_List)
    
    Debug.Print (Return_Value)
    
End Sub
```

However, as mentioned before, using the `&` is just combining the two strings together to make one string instead of telling it that it's two different things it needs to look for.

Comment: Please provide an example.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Alright, so the two named ranges I'm searching through are "List_Document_Name" and "List_Document_Type". The named range I want to return from is "List_Document_ID".

(Apparently pressing enter submits the comment. Oops. Anyway...) 

Let's say the document name I'm searching for "My Document" and the document type I want is "Sales".

Comment: Please **edit** your question to provide examples of your data.  I'm sure your description in your comment makes sense to you, but an example that can be copy/pasted into a worksheet, along with your expected output given the input, would make things much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Alright, I updated it. I did have a better example writeup in the previous comment but I kept pushing enter and submitting it by mistake and then it wouldn't let me edit it anymore. 

First time posting here so still figuring it out a little bit.

Comment: I still don't see a data example I can copy/paste into my worksheet, nor an example of what the results should look like.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't have access it `XLOOKUP` in my version of Excel, so I cannot test. But I think the issue is your use of quotes (`"`) around your search ranges.

You say: "Using "&" combines the two strings together". That is exactly what is happening, except that you are combining the strings **OF** the addresses, rather than the strings **AT** those addresses.

Try this (you will need to adjust the search ranges and criteria to suit):

```
WorksheetFunction.Xlookup("ThingToLookFor" & "OtherThingToLookFor", A1:A3&B1:B3, C1:C3)
```

If "ThingToLookFor" & "OtherThingToLookFor" are also cell references, remember to remove the `"` from those too.